# apache2 error when adding port 80 to ports.conf: apache2.service failed because the control process

Tags: apache2

I want to make my owncloud installation listen to port 80. Right now it listens to port 81. So in the apache2/ports.conf, I added

Listen 80

When I want to restart apache 2 then, it gives me:
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

When I try to find out which process might use the port, and type:
lsof -i:80
I get nothing. So no process seems to listen to that port.

What could have gone wrong?

My whole configuration:

```
Listen 81

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>

Listen 82

 # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

netstat -a |grep LISTEN gives me

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:nntps           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:nntp            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:504             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:smtp            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:microsoft-ds    0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:imaps           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:pop3s           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2020            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:xmpp-client     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:mysql         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:submission      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:netbios-ssn     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 localhost:11211         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:pop3            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:imap2           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:http            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:urd             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ip6-localhost:3350      [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:3389               [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:microsoft-ds       [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:netbios-ssn        [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:81                 [::]:*                  LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:82                 [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

/var/log/apache2/error.log says

```
[Wed Apr 04 20:26:55.673090 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1082] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal o$
[Wed Apr 04 20:26:55.673314 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1082] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Apr 04 20:27:44.980083 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1082] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 04 20:28:04.370959 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1162] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal o$
[Wed Apr 04 20:28:04.371181 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1162] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Apr 04 20:31:12.299314 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1162] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 04 20:31:12.703337 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1226] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal o$
[Wed Apr 04 20:31:12.703553 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1226] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Apr 04 20:31:31.775335 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1226] AH00052: child pid 1230 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Wed Apr 04 20:31:32.789760 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1226] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 04 20:34:07.337845 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1334] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal o$
[Wed Apr 04 20:34:07.338077 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1334] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Apr 04 20:37:03.819967 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1334] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Apr 04 20:37:30.130293 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1439] AH00163: Apache/2.4.25 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal o$
[Wed Apr 04 20:37:30.130520 2018] [core:notice] [pid 1439] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Apr 04 20:51:34.940551 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1439] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

Comment: What do the logs say?